# Accessing array returned by function in different action

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to access a 2D array returned by a function.

Below is my function returning the array:

```
Function readExcel
    'Importing and Reading an Excel into 2D Array

    Set xlwb = createObject("excel.application")
    excelpath = "H:/SomeExcel.xlsx"
    Datatable.import filePath
    row = Datatable.GetrowCount
    ReDim getCellContents(row,1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(getCellContents)
        getCellContents(i,0) = Datatable.Value("A","Global") 
        getCellContents(i,1) = Datatable.Value("B","Global")
    Next
    readExcel = getCellContents
End Function
```

I am calling the function in a different action and trying to access the array elements,

```
Dim accessArrayValues
accessArrayValues = readExcel   
MsgBox accessArrayValues(0,0)
MsgBox accessArrayValues(0,1)
```

I think there is something wrong with the way I am trying to access the array in the action.

Comment: Is your `readExcel` function defined as a Public function in a function library?

Comment: wou, truns out I hadn't made it public.
Thanks Man, I am getting the desired output now.

Comment: @PankajJaju - but aren't the functions 'Public' by default ?

Comment: Yes, in VBS they are, but not sure why I was not able to access it without making is explicitly Public.

Comment: No, in UFT you have to declare them as Public specifically.